# Pandas NaN with log

Tags: python, pandas

I got this problem "setting an array element with a sequence", any help to solve the matter? I used this to create NaN in my data to be able to calculate the log and then I need to plot it.

```
import pandas as pd 
d = np.array(Hnew) 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
df = df.mask(df < 62.5)

h = np.zeros(np.size(df))

for i in range(0, np.size(df)):
    h[i] = 5-np.log((df[i]-62.5)/0.915)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
h= 5 - np.log((df.mask(df['val']<= 62.5)['val'] - 62.5)/0.915)
```

You tried to assign the series `np.log` returned to the elements in an array of type `float64` which isn't possible (that's the reason for the message). But `np.log` already returns the series you probably want.

Please also note that I also changed `< 62.5` to `<= 62.5` because you probably would get `-inf` or an error, if you try to calculate the `log` of `0`.